# My POST request on TIdHttpServer contains strange characters, json string

Tags: json, rest, delphi, post, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have an issue with the JSON string I get when receiving a POST request. Currently this is the way I'm reading it:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Stream : TStream;
  S : string;
begin
  If ARequestInfo.Command = 'POST' then
  begin
    Stream := ARequestInfo.PostStream;
    if assigned(Stream) then
    begin
      Stream.Position := 0;
      S := UTF8ToAnsi(ReadStringFromStream(Stream));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I tried `ReadStringFromStream()` alone and with `UTF8ToAnsi()`and `AnsiToUTF8()`, but I keep getting a string that looks like this:

> '['#$A#9'{'#$A#9#9'"test":"bb",'#$A#9#9'"test":"aa"'#$A#9'}'#$A']'

I know it has something to do with encoding, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do know that the hash (#) sign denotes a character value and that the dollar ($) sign denotes hexadecimal values, do you. Thus `#$A` means character decimal 10, which happens to mean `NewLine` and `#9` means character 9 which is the `TAB` character. There is nothing unexpected in the return string. If you feed it into something that understands a `NewLine` without a preceding `CarriageReturn` it will probably look as you expected.

The debugger for exmple, uses the #-syntax for characters that cant be otherwise visually represented.

Answer (score 3):

The data you showed in your example is perfectly fine, as explained by Tom B.  You are looking at the string data in the debugger, where `#A` is a line break and `#9` is a tab character, so the actual string looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "test":"bb",
        "test":"aa"
    }
]
```

Which is valid JSON.

However, the way you are reading the data is not OK, especially if you are using a Unicode version of Delphi (2009+).  You are not passing any value to the `AByteEncoding` parameter of `ReadStringFromString()`, so it will decode the stream bytes using Indy's default encoding, which is 7bit US-ASCII by default (see the `GIdDefaultTextEncoding` variable in the `IdGlobal` unit). JSON uses UTF-8 by default, so you will corrupt the JSON if it contains any non-ASCII characters. Using `UTF8ToAnsi()` after the fact won't fix that.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Stream : TStream;
  S : string;
begin
  If ARequestInfo.CommandType = hcPOST then
  begin
    Stream := ARequestInfo.PostStream;
    if Assigned(Stream) then
    begin
      S := ReadStringFromStream(Stream, -1, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
    end
  end
end;
```

That tells Indy to decode the stream bytes as UTF-8 to UTF-16, then return the decoded string (if you are using a non-Unicode version of Delphi, the UTF-16 data will be converted to ANSI upon exit, subject to the optional `ADestEncoding` parameter of `ReadStringFromStream()`).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It says there's no overload for ReadStringFromStream with those parameters. I'm using Delphi Berlin 10.1 btw

Comment: actually after trying to read the stream even with the # characters it still works and doesn't trigger any exceptions.

Comment: @John my bad, I forgot a parameter. It is fixed now